# Robocopy misunderstanding of destination folder

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I want to create a simple script to move the entire contents of a folder up in the parent directory, and insert it in the context menu.

Here is the script. I'm trying to understand how `robocopy` uses path names with spaces inside.
Echo and pause stuff are there only for troubleshooting..

```
@echo on
set origin= %1
set destination= "%~dp1"
echo %origin%
echo %destination%
pause
robocopy %origin% %destiny% /E /MOVE /R:2 /ETA
pause
```

Comment: so, what happens if you run your script on a directory with spaces in it? If you run robocopy directly, you would have to enclose the folder names in quotes, otherwise it chokes. But you call your script with quotes around the folder names as well, right?

Comment: it takes the options in the destination, so it's like:
'Origin: C:\origin
Destination: C:\destination" \e \move \R:2 \eta\
Option: default'

Comment: what happens if you enclose the `%origin%` and the `%destination%` in quotes? Btw. is the `%destiny%` a typo that is in your script as well?

Comment: As @TheUser1024 says, if you want to handle paths with spaces you need to encapsulate them within double-quotes.  But, as-is, your actual question is hard to figure out exactly, and you comment does nothing to clarify it.  What's the actual problem you're having?  What's your actual question to us?

Comment: It's strange, because the first echo tells me that the origin path is between double-quotes, while the second one tells me that the destination path is not. So I add double-quotes with _set destination= "%~dp1"_ 
@TheUser1024 Yes, it's a typo. Corrected. Btw it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not encapsulate the path with quotes in the `set` command, you only need to do that when you attempt to use the variable in a command.

`set` sees the whole thing as a string and doesn't care about the spaces, whereas the `robocopy` command will see spaces (when `%foo%` is expanded) as parameter separators.

Any file path you pass to the batch file will need to be quoted when calling the batch file (otherwise the spaces will parse the path into multiple parameters), so to avoid having some things quoted and others not, you can use the `%~1` form to remove the quotes.

One flaw in your script as posted, however, is that if your original path passed (i.e. `%1`) has a trailing `\`, then `%~dp1` evaluates to the same path as `%1` rather than the parent.